# Why does my calculator and wolfram alpha give different answers for this integral?

Tags: integration

What is the value of $\Large e^{\int{\frac{2.8}{1.4x+2}}dx}$ ?

On my ti-nspire it gives me $49*(x+1.42857)^2$ which is actually $(7x+10)^2$

However, wolfram alpha gives me [$(1.4x+2)^2$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%28integral+of+2.8%2F%281.4x%2B2%29%29), which is actually what my calculator gave but divided by 5?

Why would it be different ?

Comment: What does the huge $e$ means?

Comment: Different constants of integration. Since you exponentiate the result, that becomes a nonzero factor.

Comment: @chubakueno: someone changed it, I think it's because the fraction was super small and hard to read.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Oh alright that makes sense I guess.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes $$\int\frac{2.8}{1.4x+2}dx=\ln(1.4x+2)^2+C $$

In Wolfram   $C=0$ but for your calculator $C=\ln25$.